# TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable, cannot show window

Tags: numpy-ndarray, python-3.8

Could someone please help me understand why

```
import numpy as np, cv2
im = np.zeros((256,256),np.uint16)
cv2.imshow('myWindow', np.zeros((256,256),np.uint16))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

opens a window as expected, while

```
import numpy as np, cv2
im = np.zeros((256,256),np.uint16)
cv2.imshow('myWindow', im((256,256),np.uint16))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

displays a

> TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

error? Any input/explanation/fix is appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? `np.zeros()` is a function. `im` is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
import numpy as np, cv2
im = np.zeros((256,256),np.uint16)
cv2.imshow('myWindow', im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```